# Taking inputs from a file in the command line in Java

Tags: java, file, parsing, command-line, command

I'm having trouble parsing a file as input through the command line for the following problem.

Consider two files about students, containing their names and passwords, and names and email addresses respectively. One would want to combine these to get a single file (in alphabetical order), with names, emails and passwords.

The input will come in via STDIN, and will have the following format:

```
NUMBER OF RECORDS 
NAME1 FIELD1 
NAME2 FIELD1 
... 
NAMEN FIELD1 
NAME1 FIELD2 
NAME2 FIELD2 
... 
NAMEN FIELD2
```

Your output should take the form:

```
NAME1' FIELD1 FIELD2 
NAME2' FIELD1 FIELD2 
... 
NAMEN' FIELD1 FIELD2
```

Where the output is sorted (hence the '). 
Thus, for example, given the following input:

```
3 
a 1 
c 2 
b 3 
b 4 
c 5 
a 6
```

Your program should provide the following output:

```
a 1 6 
b 3 4 
c 2 5
```

My Code is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Combiner 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
        BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        //first line number of students
        int numOfStudents = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
//      ins1 is the array of inputs of name and UN
        String[] ins1 = new String[numOfStudents];
        //ins2 is the array of inputs of name and Password
        String[] ins2 = new String[numOfStudents];
        //collect all inputs of Student Name, UN
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfStudents; i++)
        {
            ins1[i] = stdin.readLine();
        }
        //collect all inputs of Student Name, Password
        for (int i = 0; i<numOfStudents; i++)
        {
             ins2[i] = stdin.readLine();
        }
        //sort both arrays
        Arrays.sort(ins1);
        Arrays.sort(ins2);

         for(int i =0; i<numOfStudents; i++)
        {
            //gets the last word from each element of ins2
            String toAdd = getLast(ins2[i]);
            //concats that to each element of ins 1
            ins1[i]= ins1[i] + " " + toAdd;
        }
        //print the result
        for(int i =0; i<numOfStudents; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(ins1[i]);
        }  
    }
      public static String getLast(String x)
    {
        //splits x into an array of words seperated by a space
        String[] split = x.split(" ");
        //gets the last element in that array
        String lastWord = split[split.length - 1];
        return lastWord;
    }
}
```

I get the desired output when I input from the command line. But when I use a reference to a file such as C:\Users\Stephen\Documents\3 which is just a file that contains

```
3 
a 1 
c 2
b 3
b 4 
c 5 
a 6
```

which throws the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.ThrowFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Combiner.main(Combiner.java.10)
```

Line 10 is

```
int numOfStudents = scanner.nextInt();
```

I have no idea what's wrong with it, it works when each line is added individually through the console of my IDE or command line

Comment: are you sure the 3 is the very first thing in the input file?? there aren't any new line's before it or spaces?

Comment: yeah, I have gotten the same error on every file that I attempt to use, including those provided by the instructor

Comment: then use nextLine() and print out what you get. i am doubting it is a number. See what it is and this should help you figure what you are getting from the file for the first line

Comment: have you ever used hashsets in your class, and/or array lists? because a data structure of HashSet<String, ArrayList<Integer>> would be a good data structure to represent the input you are parsing and storing

Comment: Why use the scanner at all?  Does it behave better (reading from file) if you read the first line using 'stdin'? using: int numOfStudents = Integer.valueOf(stdin.readLine()).intValue();

Comment: My main issue that I'm trying to rectify is trying to get the inputs from the file, handling the arrays thereafter isn't the issue, but I appreciate the suggestion, I'll look into it.

Comment: @IanMc Unfortunately that didn't change the error

Comment: Please post the code where you open a File, and create a FileReader for it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the code that shows how you're attempting to provide the file name? As far as I can tell the first piece of your code that does anything is:

> scanner.nextInt();

Which is not going to read from a file, it is waiting for user input. Also I do not see where or how you are reading in from a file, perhaps I'm missing it?

Ok, so line 1 below is creating an `InputStream` and then using a `FileInputStream` to read from the File specified.

Line 2 is using the `BufferedReader` and `InputStreamReader` to assign the `InputStream` from line 1 to variable `stdin`.

Line 3 is just so you have an empty String to use to hold each line as it is read.

Lines 4-6 contain a `while` loop, which is using the `stdin.readLine()` to read each line from the file. As each line is read, it is assigned to the `line` variable, and if the content is not `null`, then it goes into the `while` loop and attempts to output the line. Inside of that `while` loop is where you would do additional processing on each line in the file. I hope this helps, I'll check back in a bit!

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Stephen\\Documents\\3");
BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line = "";
while((line = stdin.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Ok, so you want the user to provide the file name perhaps? Try adding this above the code I provided above. Then replace the path in the FileInputStream to use the variable `fileName`.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the full path to the file containing student data, then press [Enter]: " );
String fileName = scanner.next();
```

Comment: The user is supposed to enter the information, but for purposes of faster assessment, the instructor claims that the file is parsed in the same way that console lines would be. I'm not sure of a way to make it both. I may also be trying to reference the file incorrectly.

Comment: By providing System.in to your InputStreamReader, you are still looking for user input. I've added some code to the first response for easier reading, trying to put it in comments made a mess.

Comment: And the program works perfectly fine with user inputs, but in order to test on larger inputs it would be extremely cumbersome to have to input hundreds of lines each test

Comment: That only works in reference to a specific file, 3 was an arbitrary filename for my own testing purposes, I have no idea what the name of the actual assessment file would be.

Comment: I'm wondering really if there is a way to call the file via the command line such that the program interprets it as if the user was inputting it line by line.

Comment: I've added some lines that should do what you're asking, please don't hesitate to ask if you don't understand what some piece of this code is doing.